# Display decimal numbers without trailing zeros in an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a data sheet and a form in access i want to show the data in the decimal fields and i want to trim the extra zeros which is coming form the database.

e.g.:

- if 1.200 i want to display 1.2
- if 5.67890 i want 5.6789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the solution Just go to property of the text box and changed the *Format* to **General Number** and *Decimal Places*  to **Auto**